# Show Result from Parallel Ajax request in React Component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise, jsx

I'm trying to rewrite my old project in Reactjs. As I am a beginner and this is my first app, I need some assistance in understanding what is the best way to do this in the React way and how I can improve myself and this demo project.

Here is a [working demo](http://numberless-home.surge.sh/) of it.

I want to show a name as soon as its Ajax request complete instead of waiting for all to finish in Promise.

**ListManager.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import List from './List'

export class ListManager extends Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {finaldata: []}
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    const id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    this.APIres(id)
  }

  APIres (ids) {
    Promise.all(ids.map(id => fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/' + id).then(resp => resp.json().then(data => data.name))
    )).then(data => {
      data.sort()
      this.setState({finaldata: Object.assign(this.state.finaldata, data)})
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      < div>
        <h3>{this.props.title}< /h3>
        <List data={this.state.finaldata} />
      < /div >
    )
  }
}
```

**List.js**

```
'use strict'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const ListItem = ({ text }) => <li>{text}</li>

const List = ({ data }) => {
  const listNodes = data.map((value, index) => <ListItem text={value} key={index}></ListItem>)

  return <ul>{listNodes}</ul>
}
export default List
```

Some note: id array will come with a URL query like `example.com/#/?id=1,2,3,4`. I will be using react-router for this.

Comment: do you need order the same as ids order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are ways

**1 with sequense** [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vuhogi/3/edit?js,output)

all fetches start at the same time (for performance reason), but data will appear in order of ids

```
  APIres (ids) {
    ids.map(id => fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/' + id).then(resp => resp.json()) )
    .reduce((sequence,promise)=>
    sequence.then(()=>promise)
    .then(({name})=>{
        this.setState({finaldata: [...this.state.finaldata, name]});
    }), Promise.resolve());
  }
```

**2 sequense is not guaranteed** [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bifefi/5/edit?js,output)

all fetches start at the same time (for performance reason), but data will appear in order of requests responses, which may not be the same as ids order

```
  APIres (ids) {
    ids.forEach(id => fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/' + id).then(resp => resp.json())
     .then(({name})=>{
      this.setState({finaldata: [...this.state.finaldata, name]})
    }))
  }
```

**3 sorting before setState**

data will appear in order of requests responses,but ordering will be achieved through `sort()`

```
  APIres (ids) {
    ids.forEach(id => fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/' + id).then(resp => resp.json())
     .then(({name})=>{
      this.setState({finaldata: [...this.state.finaldata, name].sort()})
    }))
  }
```

Comment: i want to sort by name .. id sequence does not matter . no 3 does that . but i have little one question . what if in future fetch return name and runtime for a one id . and i want to sort based on runtime.

Comment: @VikasKapadiya the third example does order by name http://jsbin.com/zaruxam/2/edit?js,output

Comment: i know . i just said that . i am also saying what if i have name and runtime for each id instead of just name . then how to sort it ?

Comment: check this one .. i want to sort by runtime